# Which Unix book or pdf would advanced users like to keep with them?

Tags: linux, shell, application

I am looking for some books or online pdf or tutorials for advanced Linux system administration which they would always like to keep with them. I mean ones in which there are some advanced, ready to use scripts which take their Unix knowledge to next level.

Although it's practice that makes perfect, books also have a great role in that.

Comment: They are called "man pages". Also, if you run Linux, the files in /usr/src/linux/Documentation are a good source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you become an 'advanced' sysadmin, books generally no longer cover the sorts of problems you encounter.  Books are great to use as references, but once you can call yourself 'advanced' you will not be looking up reference books very often.

Personally speaking (as someone who works as a sysadmin, is not 'advanced' but nonetheless has no books on the shelf) there is no substitute for setting up a server and playing!

Comment: Absolutely - when I was first learning Linux the sage that was teaching me got me to the point of knowing what to look up myself and how to look it up and then declared me ready and set me off my myself. Problems tend to be very specific and the solutions change so rapidly it's difficult to have an absolute reference, more important is to know enough to be able to find answers for yourself, and then you can even pick up some best practice along the way - this site is a great example of that.

Comment: Sometimes, a command/library reference book can be helpful, when you're bored of searching the web, and got the feeling to slow down and to lean back. Happens quite rarely :-). Today, books about IT tend to fulfill kind of a 'once upon a time' role.. My colleagues looked at me if I were an alien, when I showed them my brand new nmap book. I bought it to support Fyodor, not to read it :-).

Answer (score 4):

You may find the following links helpful:

- http://tldp.org/guides.html             THE Linux documentation project - everything!
- http://linux.org            Linux
- http://linuxmanpages.com/           Online Linux man pages
- http://linuxselfhelp.com/           Linux Help Site
- http://linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/NFS/NFS-HOWTO-3.html            NFS
- http://unixgeeks.org/           UNIX for Geeks.
- http://computerhope.com/unix.htm#04             Linux/Unix Command List.
- http://ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-find.html         UNIX find command from IBM
- http://lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html          vi-1
- http://selectorweb.com/vi.html          vi-2
- http://pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html           Linux Command Line List
- http://acs.ucsd.edu/info/jobctrl.shtml          UNIX job control
- http://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo           sudo in Ubuntu
- http://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot            Ubuntu Dual Boot
- http://softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/find_mini_tutorial.shtml             find tutorial
- http://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/switching/C/installing-partitioning.html           Ubuntu Partitioning

Comment: The first link was excellent

Answer (score 0):

Personally I keep "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment" by W. Richard Stevens readily available. Its a good book to learn a bunch of programming tricks, too (Disclaimer: I am not an Advanced SysAdmin, may be somewhere in the middle of the range).

Answer (score 0):

`man` is your friend

Beside that, the "Linux Administration Handbook"